# Пересечение вектора с сферой(3D)

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
    u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
    v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)

    x_c = 1 * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
    y_c = 1 * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
    z_c = 1 * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))
    elev = 10.0
    rot = 80.0 / 180 * np.pi
    ax.plot_surface(x_c, y_c, z_c,  rstride=4, cstride=4, color='b', linewidth=0, alpha=0.25)


    ax.view_init(elev=elev, azim=0)

    in1d = reduce(np.intersect1d, ((U, V, W), (x_c, y_c, z_c)))
    print(in1d)
    print('Yes' if in1d else 'No')


    ax.set_xlabel('X')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z')

    plt.show()
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 3):

Вектор? Сферу? Это несколько разные понятия, вряд ли вектор может что-то пересекать.

Если речь идёт о сегменте (отрезке) прямой, то достаточно подставить параметрическое представление отрезка в уравнение сферы и найти, есть ли решения у получившегося квадратного уравнения на интервале параметра t `0..1`

```
 X = X0 + t * (X1-X0) и аналогично для Y, Z
 или    
 X = X0 + t * dx   где dx = X1-X0
```

Подставить это в уравнение сферы. Если радиус R и центр в начале координат:

```
 X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 = R^2
```

Получается уравнение

```
 (dx^2+dy^2+dz^2)*t^2 + 2*(X0*dx+Y0*dy+Z0*dz)*t + (X0^2+Y0^2+Z0^2-R^2) = 0
```

Пример:

```
R=5
P0=(-8,-6,0)
P1=(8,6,0) 
D = (16,12,0)
(dx^2+dy^2+dz^2)*t^2 + 2*(X0*dx+Y0*dy+Z0*dz)*t + (X0^2+Y0^2+Z0^2-R^2) = 0
400*t^2 - 400*t + 75 = 0
16*t^2 - 16*t + 3 = 0
D = 256 - 192 = 64
t1 = (16-8)/32 = 1/4
t1 = (16+8)/32 = 3/4
Xi1 = -8 + 16/4 = -4
Yi1 = -6 + 12/4 = -3
Xi2 = -8 + 3*16/4 = 4
Yi2 = -6 + 3*12/4 = 3
(пифагорова тройка)
```

Comment: Реализации чего - решения квадратного уравнения?

Comment: Коэффициенты квадратного уравнения нашёл?

Comment: Где в коде начальная и конечная точки - point, point2? Из них нужно вычислить разности типа `dx=point2.x-point.x` для формирования уравнения.

Comment: С математикой же не было проблем - составить квадратное уравнение. Решить, как в школе, или с использованием `numpy.roots`

Comment: В ответе же - если есть корни в диапазоне 0..1, то есть пересечения, их можно найти, подставив t в уравнения для X,Y,Z

Comment: Мой пример работает

Comment: @Paladond  Что за балет? Я тут типа сам с собой разговариваю, вопрос без вопроса остался...